# Linq query using result of another query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a query that gets data in the form of an IQueryable

```
        var assys = assetrelationshipRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.AssetId == siteAssetId)
            .Where(x => x.RelationshipTypeId == (long)AssetRelationshipTypeEnum.Parent)
            .Where(x => x.RelatedAsset.AssetTypeId == (long)AssetTypeEnum.Assembly)
            .Select(x => x.RelatedAsset.CustomAssetAttributes2);
```

For every 'assy' that is returned, I'd like to get it's AssetId and use this to get a list of 'subassys', see below. For each 'assy' record, the assyId variable should be substituted for its AssetId.

```
        var subassys = assetrelationshipRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.AssetId == assyId)
            .Where(x => x.RelationshipTypeId == (long)AssetRelationshipTypeEnum.Parent)
            .Where(x => x.RelatedAsset.AssetTypeId == (long)AssetTypeEnum.SubAssy)
            .Select(x => x.RelatedAsset.CustomAssetAttributes2);
```

I assume I'll need to use ForEach, does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Applying `ForEach` would be extremely bad approach to retrieve your desired result. You could apply `join` and `group` for that queries instead.

```
var assysQuery = assetrelationshipRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.AssetId == siteAssetId)
            .Where(x => x.RelationshipTypeId == (long)AssetRelationshipTypeEnum.Parent)
            .Where(x => x.RelatedAsset.AssetTypeId == (long)AssetTypeEnum.Assembly);
```

Then apply `join` and `group`;

```
var subAssysQuery = 
            from assy in assysQuery
            join subAssy in assetrelationshipRepository.GetAll() on assy.Id equals subAssy.AssetId
            where 
            subAssy.RelationshipTypeId == (long)AssetRelationshipTypeEnum.Parent &&
            subAssy.RelatedAsset.AssetTypeId == (long)AssetTypeEnum.Assembly
            group assy by assy.Id into g
            select new
            {
              AssyId = g.Key,
              SubAssets = g.Select(x => x.RelatedAsset.CustomAssetAttributes2),
            };
```

This should give you `CustomAssetAttributes2` value of `subassys` for per `assy` record.

> Note : Also, I suggest you to use known type for select clause instead
>   of anonymous type.